# html issue with everything ether being centered or left. i want certain divs left/centered

Tags: html, css

So i converted my several html pages to one and that messed with how i want everything done. I wanted my first div(tab) to be centered, 2nd one centered, 3rd one was fine, 4rth one to be left justified( it should default to left if no alignment is assigned), 5th is good i can fix that, 6 and 7th i want centered as well. Im mega confused on how to make each div  different alignment.

my fiddle for some of my code:       https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/5e79skm3/9/

I know why its all centered but I dont get how to single out each divs alignment. then add my next and previous button to my css so that doesnt mess with stuff.

html code:

```
<div class="">

<div id="exTab3" class="">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a id= "homeTab" href="#1b" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id= "SkillTreeTab" href="#2b" data-toggle="tab">Skill Tree</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="EquipmentTab" href="#3b" data-toggle="tab">Equipment</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="PetsTab" href="#4b" data-toggle="tab">Pets</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="SkillsTab" href="#5b" data-toggle="tab">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="QuestsTab" href="#6b" data-toggle="tab">Quests</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="ShopTab" href="#7b" data-toggle="tab">Shop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>






 <div class="tab-content clearfix">
     <!--Home-->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1b">

     <style>
                    div,
                    a {
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                </style>
                <span id="cookies">0</span>
                <br />
                <span id="rebirths">0</span>
                <br />
                <button onclick="cookieClick(); Strengthexp(); playerClicked();">Click Me!</button>
                <br />
                Cost: 10mp <button id="BigClickBtn" onclick="Bigclick(); spellUsed();">BigClick</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="antCost">50</span> <button onclick="buyAnt()" id="antCostBtn" >Buy Ant</button> <span id="ants">0</span>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="catCost">100</span> <button onclick="buyCat()" id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button> <span id="cats">0</span>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="dogCost">250</span> <button onclick="buyDog()" id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button> <span id="dogs">0</span>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="humanCost">500</span> <button onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button> <span id="humans">0</span>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>
                <br />
                Hp:<span id="MaxHitPoints">0</span> Mp:<span id="ManaPoints">0</span> 
                <br />



                <div>

         <style>
 div,
    a {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .previous {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      color: black;
        padding: 8px 16px;
    }

    .next {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
        padding: 8px 16px;
    }

    .round {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
                <button onclick="fight()" id="Fightbtn">Fight</button>
    <span id="enemyName">rat</span> &nbsp; Hp:<span id="enemyHp">10</span>
    <span>Gold: <span id="goldcoins">0</span></span>
    <a href="#" id="previous" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
    <a href="#" id="next" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
                </div>
      <br />

    </div>






    <!-- SkillTree tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
      <style>
                    div,
                    a {
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                </style>
                Skill Tree &nbsp; &nbsp; SP:<span id="SkillPoints">0</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <!--<button id="HitPointsup" onclick="HitPointsup()">Hp up</button>--> &nbsp; <button id="ManaPointsup" onclick="ManaPointsup()">Mp up</button>
                <br />
                <!--<button id="Hpregen" onclick="Hp regen()">Hp regen</button>-->
                &nbsp;
                <button id="Strengthup" onclick="Strengthup()">Str up</button> &nbsp;
                <button id="Mpreg" onclick="ManaPointsregen()">Mp regen</button>
                <br />
                <button id="Passive1" onclick="()">Passive skill</button> &nbsp; <button id="Passive2" onclick="Hp up()">Passive skill</button> &nbsp; <button id="Passive3" onclick="Hp up()">Passive skill</button> &nbsp; <button id="Passiveskill" onclick="Hp up()">Passive skill</button> &nbsp;
                <br />
                <span id="rebirths">0</span>




    </div>

     <!-- Equipment Tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3b">
<div id="Equipmentradios" style="width: 100px;float:left; ">
        <font size="+2"> <b> Equipment </b></font>
        </div>
       <br>
       <br>
            <div    style="width: 430px;float:left;  text-align: left  ">
            <span id="Woodsword">Wood Sword  <input id="woodsword"   type="radio" name="Sword">
            <span id="Silversword"> Silver Sword  <input id="silverswordr"   type="radio" name="Sword">
            <span id="Goldsword">Gold Sword  <input id="goldswordr"   type="radio" name="Sword">
            <span id="Diamondsword">Diamond Sword <input id="diamondswordr"   type="radio" name="Sword">
             </div>

                <div   style="width: 430px;float:left; text-align: left  ">
           <span id="Leatherhelm">Leather Helm <input id="leatherhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
           <span id="Silverhelm"> Silver Helm<input id="silverhelmr"   type="radio" name="Helm">
           <span id="Goldhelm"> Gold Helm <input id="goldhelmr"   type="radio" name="Helm">
           <span id="Diamondhelm"> Diamond Helm <input id="diamondhelmr"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            </div>

           <div   style="width: 430px;float:left; text-align: left ">
            <span id="Leatherboots">Leather Boots <input id="leatherboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            <span id="Silverboots"> Silver Boots <input id="silverbootsr"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            <span id="Goldboots"> Gold Boots <input id="goldbootsr"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            <span id="Diamondboots"> Diamond Boots <input id="diamondbootsr"   type="radio" name="Boots">
             </div>

            <div   style="width: 430px;float:left; text-align: left   ">
            <span id="Leatherarmor">Leather Armor <input id="leatherarmor"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            <span id="Silverarmor"> Silver Armor <input id="silverarmors"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            <span id="Goldarmor"> Gold Armor <input id="goldarmors"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            <span id="Diamondarmor"> Diamond Armor <input id="diamondarmors"   type="radio" name="Armor">
                <label class="radio">


                    </div>
                <div id="crafting" style="width: 350px;   float:right; left: 650px; top: 55px; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; position: absolute; left: 680px; top: 75px; margin:10px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  <font size="+2"> <b>Forge</b></font>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2">Silver Sword <button id="SilverSwordBtn" onclick="buySsword(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button> Gold Sword <button id="GoldSwordBtn" onclick="buyGsword(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button> Diamond Sword <button id="DiamondSwordBtn" onclick="buyDsword(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button></font>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Silver Helm <button id="SilverHelmBtn" onclick="buyShelm(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;Gold Helm &nbsp;<button id="GoldHelmBtn" onclick="buyGhelm(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button>&nbsp;Diamond Helm &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="DiamondHelmBtn" onclick="buyDhelm();checkWunlock();">Craft</button></font>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> &nbsp;Silver Boots <button id="SilverBootsBtn" onclick="buySboots(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;Gold Boots <button id="GoldBootsBtn" onclick="buyGboots(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;Diamond Boots <button id="DiamondBootsBtn" onclick="buyDboots(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button></font>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> Silver Armor <button id="SilverArmorBtn" onclick="buySarmor(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button> Gold Armor&nbsp; <button id="GoldArmorBtn" onclick="buyGarmor(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button>&nbsp; Diamond Armor <button id="DiamondArmorBtn" onclick="buyDarmor(); checkWunlock();">Craft</button></font>
                    <br />

                        </div>
                        </div>

















<!-- Pets Tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4b">


        <font size="+2"> <b> Pets </b></font>


<div id="turtle" class="control">
   <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
   </label><img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100"> Lv 
   <span id="Turtlelv">1</span> <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> / <span 
  id="TurtleMexp">100</span></div>

       <br />
       <br />

       <div id="lizard" class="control">
         <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" onclick="Lizardandmagic()" id="lizard-radio">
        </label><img src="lizard2.png" alt="lizard" height="42" width="42"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Lv <span 
    id="Lizardlv">1</span> <span id="LizardCexp">0</span> / <span 
    id="LizardMexp">100</span></div>
       <br />
        <div id="wolf" class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" onclick="Wolfandstrength()"  id="wolf-radio">
           </label><img src="wolf.png" alt="wolf" height="60" width="60"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Lv <span id="Wolflv">1</span> <span 
    id="WolfCexp">0</span> / <span id="WolfMexp">100</span></div>
       <br />
        <div id="mole" class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" onclick="Moleandchance()"  id="mole-radio">
           </label><img src="mole.png" alt="mole" height="50" width="60"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Lv <span id="Molelv">1</span> <span 
    id="MoleCexp">0</span> / <span id="MoleMexp">100</span></div>
           <br />
      Str+<span id="Strength">0</span>
        <br />
      Mgc+<span id="Magic">0</span>
           <br />
      Mpr+<span id="Manaregen">0</span>
           <br />
      Minechance+<span id="Minechance">0</span>
            <br />
           Feed
           <select id="PetFood" >
                        <option value="Shrimp">Shrimp</option>
                        <option value="Bass">Bass</option>
                        <option value="Salmon">Salmon</option>
                        <option value="Shark">Shark</option>
                       </select>
        For:&nbsp;<span id="ExpAmount">0</span> exp &nbsp;<button onclick="GiveFood()" id="SellBtn" >Feed</button>

        </div>
```

I expect when you change tabs for tab 1 to be centered 2 centered, and so on what i described on top. a way to change what alignment each tab is. but at the moment i cant get them to do both. its ether all left or all centered. im guessing how i have it effects the whole html page. if i can get help adding to my css the next and previous button and a bit for each div that would help me a ton. there is a div id for 7 divs i think . 1b , 2b,3b,4b,5b,6b,7b.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the desired results?

Comment: sure sorry was at work all day. I will  do several.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qazofq   , centered  for first tab,  http://prntscr.com/qazoiu  , centered for next tab, http://prntscr.com/qazoox,  my third tab is fine in my ide not sure if its centered or not i think it is,   http://prntscr.com/qazots   , left justified for fourth tab. this was original just doing a div with no edits to css but its takeing centered from previous part. then last 3 can be like this  http://prntscr.com/qazp52   ,http://prntscr.com/qazp6l , http://prntscr.com/qazp8d

Comment: so centered, centered, centered, left, centered,centered, centered        i think or the 2 with boxes can be left.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ended up fixing it

css addition:

```
.centerDiv {
  text-align: center;
}
.leftDiv {
  text-align: left;
}
```

then I added this to my div class

```
<div class="tab-pane leftDiv"  id="4b">
```

So i ended up using classes to change what each div was aligned to

made it so i just had to add this to my one i wanted left. very nice way to align divs using classes.